# Java: how to read the "-" in the user int input

Tags: java, input, int

I've been trying to get the java to read the "-" for getting the phone number as a user input... Idk how, help!

Comment: And can we see your code with which you've been tryin that?

Comment: You should read it as a `String` and do your parsing from there...

Comment: read user input as string and split it by - then convwert it to int String str = "st1-st2-st3";
String delimiter = "-";
String[] temp;
temp = str.split(delimiter);
for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
System.out.println(temp[i]);

The output is:
st1
st2
st3

Comment: what if I were to print the results in the different void method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the phone no");
     String phoneNo = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Phone No: " + phoneNo);
     scan.close();
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter the phone no
122-121-121
Phone No: 122-121-121
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String phoneNumber = xxx-xxx-xxx;

for(int i = 0;i<phoneNumber.length();i++){

   if(phoneNumber[i] == '-')

    {
        System.out.println(phoneNumber[i]);

    }

}
```